# Finding value in json string

Tags: javascript, json

Below is what I have as JSON String.

```
{
    "ID_A0001":{"areaID":"A0001","shopID":"SH004","quantity":14},
    "ROW_INFO":{"areaID":"VARCHAR","shopID":"VARCHAR","quantity":"INT"},
    "ID_A0002":{"areaID":"A0002","shopID":"SH008","quantity":18}
}
```

What I want is to get the `JSONObject` which have ID as `ID_A` i.e. `ID_A0001` & `ID_A0002`.

I was thinking of using `jsonObject.getString("ID_A")`, but that is not possible. Could someone tell me what should I do so that I will get as below output.

```
{
    "ID_A0001":{"areaID":"A0001","shopID":"SH004","quantity":14},
    "ID_A0002":{"areaID":"A0002","shopID":"SH008","quantity":18}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does what you want, assuming the object you posted is stored in `obj`. In case you actually have a JSON *string* instead of an object, use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string to a JavaScript object.

```
var obj2 = {};
for(var key in obj) {
    if(key.substr(0, 4) == 'ID_A') {
        obj2[key] = obj[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the json object you have mentioned, you can modifiy it as follows.

```
 var jsontest={
    ID_A0001:{"areaID":"A0001","shopID":"SH004","quantity":14},
    ROW_INFO:{"areaID":"VARCHAR","shopID":"VARCHAR","quantity":"INT"},
    ID_A0002:{"areaID":"A0002","shopID":"SH008","quantity":18}
        };

for(var key in jsontest) {
    if(key.substring(0,4)=='ID_A')
    alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + jsontest[key].areaID);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FBLvP/

Here is a useful link which shows us how to get the list of keys from a json object
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-1-6-to-find-an-array-of-an-objects-keys/[1](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-1-6-to-find-an-array-of-an-objects-keys/)